# Rendering parts into different zones in Orchard CMS

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I'm new to Orchard CMS and wondered if it was possible to render content parts setup in the page content type into a different zone rather than the content itself.

For instance, I setup a TextField which holds an image url to be used as a page Title but is placed in a different area from the content itself.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean sending parts to a zone that is not inside the top-level Content zone, you can try this approach: http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/03/26/dispatching-orchard-shapes-to-arbitrary-zones.aspx
We are also considering various extensions to placement for future versions of Orchard.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for @bertrand-le-roy, thanks for the article and hope I continue to enjoy working with orchard cms.

Comment: I believe the Placement.info file now supports this in version 1.5 of Orchard. ex: <Place Parts_Title="/AsideSecond:1" />

Comment: This saved my life! I couldn't work out why my change of the placement didn't work initially. When I placed the '/' in front of the part it worked like magic. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

As of Orchard 1.5 you can inject a part into any zone using your theme's placement.info file. This uses [zone placement](https://docs.orchardcore.net/projects/O1/en/latest/Documentation/Understanding-placement-info/#top-level-zone-placement).

Here is an example that would place blog post's tags in the AssideFirst zone when the blog post was being shown in detail view.

```
<Placement>
    <Match ContentType="BlogPost">
        <Match DisplayType="Detail">
            <Place Parts_Tags_ShowTags="/AssideFirst:1"/>
        </Match>
    </Match>
</Placement>
```

The number after the zone name is the position. A smaller number will make it appear above other widgets in this zone and a larger number will make it appear lower down.

Answer (score 2):

You can customize content parts' display properties via **[Placement.info](https://docs.orchardcore.net/projects/O1/en/latest/Documentation/Understanding-placement-info/)** file. It's a very simple, yet powerful tool that allows you to change rendering zones, parts' ordering and such.

Could you please elaborate more about your scenario?

Comment: Although this wasn't what I was looking for at the time, your advice surrounding the Placement.info file has allowed me to resolve another issue. Great advice @pszmyd